# does a user changing the title / slug cause an issue if i continue to get the correct post by pk?

Tags: django, url, slug

Currently i have a django project where a user can ask a question and the title becomes the slug. MEaning the url is website/pk/slug

To get to the url i use a basic DetailView which just uses the model.

**URLs**

```
path('question/<int:pk>/<str:slug>/', QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='question-detail'),
path('question/<int:pk>/<str:slug>/update/', QuestionUpdateView.as_view(), name='question-update'),
```

**View**

```
class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
```

When the user changes the title of the question, i do not update the slug but only the title.

```
class QuestionUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        question = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == question.author:
            return True
        return False
```

This mean is the original url upon question creation was website/1245/How-do-i-blah i can still get to the question with any slug after website/1245/ i would think this might be a problem but i cannot see why, as google will index the slug and as i am looking up by pk if the title changes it should automatically return the right question.

Why do i think this might cause problems in the future? And should i be looking up the question by pk and slug.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would be able to still get the url because the code for the views check only the pk if passed. If you want that **both** pk and slug should match you can set `query_pk_and_slug` to be True in your view:

```
class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    query_pk_and_slug = True
```

Generally this might be a problem for the SEO of your website (since the search engine would consider it to be different page if the slug changes, (assuming that pk will never change)) but otherwise I don't think it should cause any issues.
Considering that you say that you don't change the slug it should not be much of an issue if you set `query_pk_and_slug` as above.